# MVC4 to MVC5 upgrade index was out of range on account controller after startup.cs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, oauth, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I am experiencing a problem while upgrading from MVC4 to MVC5 in regards to the external authentication providers. I have changed added the Startup.cs file as per the default MVC5 application and added the AccountViewModel and IdentityModel and the required Microsoft.Owin nuget packages but I am getting this error after startup.cs finishes and it iterates through the account controller:

**Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index**

```
var loginProviders = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes();
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(MetaLearning.Startup))]
namespace ProjectName
{
  public partial class Startup
  {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
  }
}
```

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter;
using Owin;
using System;
using ProjectName.Models;

namespace ProjectName
{
  public partial class Startup
  {
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    }
  }
}
```

**Global_asax.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Data.Entity;
using MetaLearning.Data;
using MetaLearning.Data.DAL;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.IdentityModel;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Services;
using System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using WebMatrix.WebData;

namespace MetaLearning
{
  // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
  // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

  public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
  {
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ProjectNameContext", "ProjectNameUser", "UserID", "Username", autoCreateTables: true);
    }

    ...........................

  }
}
```

**IdentityModel.cs**

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace ProjectName.Models
{
  // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
  {
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
  }

  public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
  {
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("ProjectNameContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

}

**AccountController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Owin;
using MetaLearning.Models;

namespace MetaLearning
{
  [Authorize]
  public class AccountController : Controller
  {
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/ConfirmEmail
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
    {
        if (userId == null || code == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return View("ConfirmEmail");
        }
        else
        {
            AddErrors(result);
            return View();
        }
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/ForgotPassword
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ForgotPassword()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/ForgotPassword
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user either does not exist or is not confirmed.");
                return View();
            }

            // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
            // Send an email with this link
            // string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
            // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);       
            // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
            // return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/ForgotPasswordConfirmation
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ForgotPasswordConfirmation()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/ResetPassword
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ResetPassword(string code)
    {
        if (code == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/ResetPassword
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "No user found.");
                return View();
            }
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, model.Code, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
                return View();
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/ResetPasswordConfirmation
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ResetPasswordConfirmation()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Disassociate
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Disassociate(string loginProvider, string providerKey)
    {
        ManageMessageId? message = null;
        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.RemoveLoginAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), new UserLoginInfo(loginProvider, providerKey));
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            message = ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess;
        }
        else
        {
            message = ManageMessageId.Error;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = message });
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/Manage
    public ActionResult Manage(ManageMessageId? message)
    {
        ViewBag.StatusMessage =
            message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been changed."
            : message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been set."
            : message == ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess ? "The external login was removed."
            : message == ManageMessageId.Error ? "An error has occurred."
            : "";
        ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = HasPassword();
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Manage
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Manage(ManageUserViewModel model)
    {
        bool hasPassword = HasPassword();
        ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = hasPassword;
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
        if (hasPassword)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
                    await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
                }
                else
                {
                    AddErrors(result);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // User does not have a password so remove any validation errors caused by a missing OldPassword field
            ModelState state = ModelState["OldPassword"];
            if (state != null)
            {
                state.Errors.Clear();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                IdentityResult result = await UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.NewPassword);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess });
                }
                else
                {
                    AddErrors(result);
                }
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/ExternalLogin
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
        // Request a redirect to the external login provider
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
        var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(loginInfo.Login);
        if (user != null)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
            return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
        }
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/LinkLogin
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LinkLogin(string provider)
    {
        // Request a redirect to the external login provider to link a login for the current user
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("LinkLoginCallback", "Account"), User.Identity.GetUserId());
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/LinkLoginCallback
    public async Task<ActionResult> LinkLoginCallback()
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(XsrfKey, User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.Error });
        }
        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), loginInfo.Login);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Manage");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.Error });
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Manage");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
            var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // SendEmail(user.Email, callbackUrl, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link");

                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/LogOff
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginFailure
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ExternalLoginFailure()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult RemoveAccountList()
    {
        var linkedAccounts = UserManager.GetLogins(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        ViewBag.ShowRemoveButton = HasPassword() || linkedAccounts.Count > 1;
        return (ActionResult)PartialView("_RemoveAccountPartial", linkedAccounts);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && UserManager != null)
        {
            UserManager.Dispose();
            UserManager = null;
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Helpers
    // Used for XSRF protection when adding external logins
    private const string XsrfKey = "XsrfId";

    private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
    }

    private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager));
    }

    private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
    {
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
        }
    }

    private bool HasPassword()
    {
        var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (user != null)
        {
            return user.PasswordHash != null;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void SendEmail(string email, string callbackUrl, string subject, string message)
    {
        // For information on sending mail, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
    }

    public enum ManageMessageId
    {
        ChangePasswordSuccess,
        SetPasswordSuccess,
        RemoveLoginSuccess,
        Error
    }

    private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }

    private class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
    {
        public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri)
            : this(provider, redirectUri, null)
        {
        }

        public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri, string userId)
        {
            LoginProvider = provider;
            RedirectUri = redirectUri;
            UserId = userId;
        }

        public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
        public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
            if (UserId != null)
            {
                properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;
            }
            context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}